# Hash a password using Junipers $9$ algorithm PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption

I need to hash a password using Junipers $9$ algorithm. After some
research I found a convenient Perl library named
[Crypt::Juniper](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-Juniper/lib/Crypt/Juniper.pm),
which allows you to decrypt $9$ passwords. Anyway that this can be
done using php?. I've created a portal that connects to a Juniper
router which  queries a stored password and if it is a match with the
users password it allows access, but for that to happen I need to hash 
the users input using Junipers encryption algorithm..

Comment: The source code of the aforementioned module is extremely straightfoward. You could easily port it to PHP.

Comment: Nit: If you can decrypt it, it's not a hashing algorithm, it's an encryption algorithm.

Comment: @ikegami  1) If it does not have a [user defined] key (which this, just like cisco's type 7, does not),then it is not encryption, it is merely obfuscation--used for only for "cursory" security.  2) Hashes can't be "decrypted", but they can be "cracked" with brute force searches.  This is why you still need to keep hashes confidential, still need a strong password, and why the hash has "salt" added.

Comment: @Andrew, None of that contradicts what I said. 1) "Decrpyt" doesn't apply to obfuscation either. 2) I didn't say hashes couldn't be brute forced.

Comment: "it's an encryption algorithm" (in reference to JNPR type 9) is what I read, and that is incorrect.  type9 is obfuscation.